# Can you call sqlplus with function parameters

Tags: sql, bash, oracle

So I have something like the following inside a bash script:

```
sqlplus un/pw@db \@xxx.sql $PARAM1 $PARAM2 <<EOF > $LOGPATH
quit
EOF
```

As this gets often called in the script with different parameters, I would like to extract this code into a function.

Unfortunately I can't get the parameters to work correctly.

I have tried the following:

```
do_sql() {
sqlplus un/pw@db $1 << EOF >> $2
quit
EOF
}

do_sql "\@xxx.sql $PARAM1 $PARAM2" "$LOGPATH"
```

AND

```
do_sql() {
sqlplus un/pw@db << EOF >> $2
start $1
quit
EOF
}

do_sql "xxx.sql $PARAM1 $PARAM2" "$LOGPATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just issue you sqlplus command like this:

```
sqlplus un/pw@db \@xxx.sql $PARAM1 $PARAM2
```

Don't forget to add the

```
exit;
```

at the end of your sql file.